# Grails db-migration plugin - sql vs 'bundled changes'

Tags: mysql, grails, liquibase

Background:
I have a backend for web application written in Grails, which is communicating with MySQL database. I am using the Grails database migration plugin to control the database structure, with updateOnStart set to true (I use the plugin's command line interface rarely).

Question:
Is there any practical difference between using SQL queries and 'bundled changes' in the change sets?

Example:
Is there any reason why I shoul e.g. favour:

```
addColumn(tableName: 'table_x'){
    column(name: 'new_column', type: 'int', defaultValue: 0){
        constraints(nullable: 'false')
    }
}
```

over

```
sql(sql: 'ALTER TABLE table_x ADD COLUMN new_column INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;')
```

? Or those two are completely interchangeable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the SQL you author. As long as your write portable SQL then it wouldn't matter, and that only matters if you target a different type of database that doesn't support the SQL you've authored.